# Python shell not running crawler

Tags: python, scrapy, pycharm

i had to try this code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.cmdline import execute
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from metacritic.items import MetacriticItem
class MetacriticSpider(scrapy.spider):
name = "metacritic" # Name of the spider, to be used when crawling
    allowed_domains = ["metacritic.com"] # Where the spider is allowed to go
start_urls = [
    "http://www.metacritic.com/browse/games/title/pc?page=0"
]
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) # The XPath selector
    sites = hxs.select('//li[contains(@class, "product game_product")]/div[@class="product_wrap"]')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = MetacriticItem()
        item['title'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_title"]/a/text()').extract()
        item['link'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_title"]/a/@href').extract()
        item['cscore'] = site.select('div[@class="basic_stat product_score brief_metascore"]/div/div/span[contains(@class, "data metascore score")]/text()').extract()
        item['uscore'] = site.select('div[@class="more_stats condensed_stats"]/ul/li/span[contains(@class, "data textscore textscore")]/text()').extract()
        item['date'] = site.select('div[@class="more_stats condensed_stats"]/ul/li/span[@class="data"]/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

i already try some way to fix this code, but i always get an error 
/home/kautsar/metacritic 2/metacritic/spiders/metacritic_spider.py:3: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: Module `scrapy.spider` is deprecated, use `scrapy.spiders` instead
  from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kautsar/metacritic 2/metacritic/spiders/metacritic_spider.py", line 6, in 
    class MetacriticSpider(scrapy.spider):
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    module.**init**() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
    anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
...
class MetacriticSpider(scrapy.spider):
```

As you can see, scrapy.spider is a module name.  Your class tries to inherit from it.  Typically, your class should inherit from another class- probably BaseSpider in this case.